# ¿Cómo impedir el uso de una suite de cifrado en SSLCipherSuite?

Tags: linux, apache, ssl, openssl, rhel

**Hola a todos**, buen día, tarde, noche. Voy al grano:

**CONTEXTO.** Apache/2.4.37, OpenSSL 1.1.1g FIPS sobre un Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.3 (Ootpa)

**QUÉ QUIERO HACER.** Necesito realizar las configuraciones SSL necesarias para que los sitios de mi servidor Apache, usen el protocolo `TLSv1.2` con las suites de cifrado HIGH y MEDIUM, e impedir el uso del cifrado `ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384`.

**PROBLEMA.** Logro usar las suites HIGH y MEDIUM, pero no logro impedir el uso de ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384. La herramienta [SSLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) siempre me informa que los sitios de mi servidor siguen usando el cifrado en cuestión.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**QUÉ ESTOY HACIENDO.** Esta es la configuración SSL que tengo en el vhost default en mi ssl.conf (aplica a todos los sitios). La parte `!ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384` debería impedir el uso de ese cifrado, ¡pero no lo hace!

```
SSLEngine on
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.3
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5:!SEED:!IDEA:!ECDHE:!DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:!ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/localhost.key
```

Cualquier comentario, ayuda, será invaluable.

**EDITO:** AL correr el comando `openssl ciphers -v 'HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5:!SEED:!IDEA:!ECDHE:!DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:!ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384' | grep AES256-GCM-SHA384`, la salida es:

```
DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH Au=DSS Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD 
RSA-PSK-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=RSAPSK Au=RSA Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD 
DHE-PSK-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DHEPSK Au=PSK Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD 
AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA Au=RSA Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD 
PSK-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=PSK Au=PSK Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
```

Comment: Por salud mental, yo deshabilitaría TLSv1.1 también, que ya está deprecado. Lo otro: si yo hago `openssl ciphers -v 'HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5:!SEED:!IDEA:!ECDHE:!DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:!ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384' | grep AES256-GCM-SHA384` no sale el algoritmo que te reporta. Así pues, estás seguro que estás modificando el ssl.conf que corresponde?

Comment: @Alfabravo a mí sí me aparece el algoritmo `AES256-GCM-SHA384`

Comment: @Alfabravo, muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Eso es nuevo para mí. ¿Qué es lo que devuelve el comando que pones? Es decir, ¿debo entender que tu comando devuelve una lista de todos los cifrados que no se usarán? En mi siguiente comentario pongo el resultado del comando en mi servidor.

Comment: DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
RSA-PSK-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=RSAPSK   Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
DHE-PSK-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DHEPSK   Au=PSK  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
AES256-GCM-SHA384       TLSv1.2 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
PSK-AES256-GCM-SHA384   TLSv1.2 Kx=PSK      Au=PSK  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD

Comment: @Fedex7501 recuerda que el OP busca evitar que esté disponible `ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384`. El grep es una ayuda visual nada más, no es que salga o no exactamente lo que busca el grep

Comment: @BerkeleyNow pues mira que openssl dice que con esa configuración que dices que usas, no estaría disponible ese algoritmo. Seguimos con la duda sobre si ese archivo conf sí está afectando la configuración de tu sitio :/  PD. Por favor, no añadas info en comentarios, siempre elige [edit] la pregunta

Comment: @Alfabravo mis isculpas, ya entendí. Pues entonces una forma fácil de probar no sería desactivar el ssl en ese archivo de configuración y ver si realmente afecta algo?

Comment: @Fedex7501 eso o ver si está reiniciando el Apache cuando hace esos cambios :/

Answer (score 0):

Me respondo a mí mismo. Resultó que la configuración que mencioné en la pregunta que formulé al abrir este post, efectivamente era configuración válida, estaba bien. Esa configuración se activó haciendo las siguientes dos cosas:

1. Reiniciar la máquina (sólo reiniciar Apache no servía de nada), supongo que algo estaba pegado ahí, caché quizá.
2. Yo estaba poniendo la configuración en el vhost default del ssl.conf, y por alguna razón que desconozco, esa configuración no se estaba heredando a los vhosts particulares para cada sitio web (ni reiniciando la máquina esto funcionó). Por tanto, después de reiniciar la máquina la configuración surtió efecto pero poniéndola en cada vhost particular.